# adding my comment system to the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments

i have a comment system associated to a shipment model in my app where a user can have many shipments and a shipment can have many comments.
Everything is working perfectly the only problem is that i want my whole comment system to be shown in the index page of my model currently it is in the show page.

when i try to put it on the index page i get an error:

```
undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass
```

**My Controllers**

*shipment_controller.rb*

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_shipment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /shipments
  # GET /shipments.json
  def index
    @shipments = Shipment.all
  end

  # GET /shipments/1
  # GET /shipments/1.json
  def show
    @comments = Comment.where(shipment_id: @shipment)
  end

  # GET /shipments/new
  def new
    @shipment = Shipment.new
  end

  # GET /shipments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /shipments
  # POST /shipments.json
  def create
    @shipment = current_user.shipments.new(shipment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shipment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shipment, notice: 'Shipment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shipment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shipment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shipments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /shipments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shipment.update(shipment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @shipment, notice: 'Shipment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shipment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }


      format.json { render json: @shipment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shipments/1
  # DELETE /shipments/1.json
  def destroy
    @shipment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to shipments_url, notice: 'Shipment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_shipment
      @shipment = Shipment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def shipment_params
      params.require(:shipment).permit(:name, :description, :from, :to, :date, :pay)
    end
end
```

*comments_controller.rb*

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

      def create
        @shipment = Shipment.find(params[:shipment_id])
        @comment = Comment.create(params[:comment].permit(:content))
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id
        @comment.shipment_id = @shipment.id

        if @comment.save
          redirect_to shipment_path(@shipment)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

**My routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  resources :shipments do
    resources :comments
  end
   root 'shipments#index'
end
```

**Shipment View**

*show.html.erb*

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
    <strong><%= current_user.full_name %></strong>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @shipment.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>From:</strong>
  <%= @shipment.from %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>To:</strong>
  <%= @shipment.to %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @shipment.date %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Pay:</strong>
  <%= @shipment.pay %>
</p>

      <div id="comments">
  <h2 class="comment_count">
    <%= pluralize(@shipment.comments.count, "comment") %>
  </h2>
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment">
      <p class="full_name">
        <%= comment.user.full_name %>
      </p>
      <p class="content">
        <%= comment.content %>
      </p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render "comments/form" %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_shipment_path(@shipment) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', shipments_path %>
```

**Comments View render**

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for([@shipment, @shipment.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :content, label: "Reply to thread" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

**index.html.erb without comments**

```
<h1>Listing Shipments</h1>

<%= link_to "Post a new Shipment", new_shipment_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>

<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
<div class="shipment">
<h3><strong><%= shipment.user.full_name%></strong></h3>
<h5><strong>DESCRIPTION: </strong><%= shipment.description %></h5>
  <div class="meta">
    <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(shipment.created_at) + " ago" %> |
    <%= link_to "show", shipment %>
    <span class="admin"> 
      | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_shipment_path(shipment) %> |
      <%= link_to "Delete", shipment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Hey! Are you sure! You wanna delete this shipment??"} %>
  </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

**index.html.erb with comment system**

```
<h1>Listing Shipments</h1>

<%= link_to "Post a new Shipment", new_shipment_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>

<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
<div class="shipment">
<h3><strong><%= shipment.user.full_name%></strong></h3>
<h5><strong>DESCRIPTION: </strong><%= shipment.description %></h5>
  <div class="meta">
    <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(shipment.created_at) + " ago" %> |
    <%= link_to "show", shipment %>
    <span class="admin"> 
      | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_shipment_path(shipment) %> |
      <%= link_to "Delete", shipment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Hey! Are you sure! You wanna delete this shipment??"} %>
  </span>
    </div>
  </div>
          <div id="comments">
  <h2 class="comment_count">
    <%= pluralize(@shipment.comments.count, "comment") %>
  </h2>
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment">
      <p class="full_name">
        <%= comment.user.full_name %>
      </p>
      <p class="content">
        <%= comment.content %>
      </p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render "comments/form" %>
  <% end %>
```

**After Pavan's Answer**

*Error*

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Shipment with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/shipments_controller.rb:9:in `index'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
 (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within re
scues/layout (36.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.
1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
```

Comment: Please post the index page code

Comment: added the index page please have a look @Pavan

Answer (score 0):

You've got an ivar `@comments` that doesn't appear to be defined...Try `@shipment.comments.each`

Comment: He is trying to do it in the index page and the show method has `@comments` defined. Your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I want my whole comment system to be shown in the index page of my
>   model currently it is in the show page

You need to loop through `@shipments` in the ***index view*** like below

```
<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
  <% shipment.comments.each do |comment| %>
    ----rest of the code---
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

***Update:***

You are getting the error here in this line `<%= pluralize(@shipment.comments.count, "comment") %>`. You just need to change it to

`<%= pluralize(shipment.comments.count, "comment") %>`

And you need to modify the comments iteration part like I said above.

Comment: @Denialsmith Updated! Have a look.

Comment: nope it just changed the error sir now its saying:
`Couldn't find Shipment with 'id'=`

Comment: @Denialsmith In which line you get that error now? Please update the question with the error log.

Comment: Just look at the issue again i had updated it with the error log @pavan

Comment: @Denialsmith Just use `shipment` instead of `@shipment` in this line `<%= pluralize(@shipment.comments.count, "comment") %>`

Comment: @Denialsmith Revert back  the changes in the index method to original and try again

Comment: sorry but i didn't get u revert to original means

Comment: @Denialsmith Keep the code in index method as original and follow my updated answer

Comment: sorry to say but no id does not work:
` Showing C:/Sites/aaa/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @Denialsmith Do you have any data in shipments table?

Comment: Try this `<%= pluralize(shipment.try(:comments).count, "comment") %>`

Comment: and no the same error i mentioned in the previous comment i also tried deleting everything from my database shipments and users